# Using boost::function with templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost, bind

I have a problem with boost::function along with template functions. The scenario is as follows;

I want to run a function in another function called "setter". my function is something like

```
data.totalSize(TotalSize);
```

totalSize function input argument's type is "uint32_t" and output argument's type is "void".

So I decide to use boost::function; Below is my code:

```
setter(boost::bind(&myIDL::payload::totalSize,boost::ref(data),_1),(TotalSize));
```

and the setter implementation is

```
template<typename Outer>
inline void setter(boost::function<void(Outer)> myFunc, Outer myValue)
{
   myFunc(myValue);
}
```

I will get the following compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to setter(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void,myIDL::payload, unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<myIDL::payload>, boost::arg<1> > >, quint32&)'
```

It seems that boost::function does not understand my template type. So I decide to write it as below:

```
template<typename Outer>
inline void setter(boost::function<void(unit32_t)> myFunc, Outer myValue)
{
   myFunc(myValue);
}
```

And it works! So I want to know how to solve my problem. Thanks in advance for your helps.

Best Regards,
Reza

Comment: Don't take `boost::function`, let the compiler deduce the type of a function object. `boost::function` can't be deduced from what `boost::bind` returns

Comment: Dear @Prior, Could you please explain more? Actually I don not get your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template argument type deduction only *deduces* types, it doesn't consider any conversions.
Just like the compiler didn't fail to inform you, the result of `boost::bind` yields a prvalue of some unspeakable type:

```
boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void,myIDL::payload
                       , unsigned int>
                       , boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<myIDL::payload>
                                         , boost::arg<1> > >
```

which, clearly, is *not the same as*:

```
boost::function<void(Outer)>
```

That is, type template parameter `Outer` cannot be deduced from the type of an argument expression. A solution is to accept *any* function object:

```
template <typename F, typename Outer>
inline void setter(F myFunc, Outer myValue)
{
   myFunc(myValue);
}
```

or put `Outer` in a non-deduced context (and pay the price of type-erasure):

```
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>

inline void setter(boost::function<void(typename boost::mpl::identity<Outer>::type)> myFunc
                 , Outer myValue)
{
   myFunc(myValue);
}
```